# this.getField value distributions

Tags: javascript, pdf

Hi guys I have been stuck at this for quite a while.
So the situation is like this .

1. There are 4 fields
2. So I would like it when a user key in a code vv1 for example, the javascript will then distribute the translation of that code in 3 separate fields.

I have tried the below code but unfortunately, it will only reflect the last value no matter what code I key in.

```
var x = this.getField("texta");
var b = this.getField("texta-1");
var c = this.getField("texta-2");
var d = this.getField("texta-3"); //  setting the field name

var y = x.value.toLowerCase();
y = y.replace(/\s/g, ''); // change the code value to lower case and  remove spaces.

if(y == 'vv01'||y== 'vv1'){b.value = "0 "}{c.value = "6"}{d.value = "180"};
if(y == 'vv02'||y== 'vv2'){b.value = "0 "}{c.value = "9"}{d.value = "225"};
if(y == 'vv03'||y == 'vv3' ){b.value = "0 "}{c.value = "12"}{d.value = "300"};// Translate the code to its intended vale 3 examples written here.
```

Meaning when a user key in vv1  in "texta" field  the value that will reflect in "texta" = vv1 , and the value that supposed to reflect in  "texta-1" = o  value in "texta-2" = 6  and "text-3"= 180  but unfortunately no matter what code I key in it only reflect the last code I coded.

Comment: Have you considered writing `{b.value = "0 "; c.value = "6"; d.value = "180"}` instead of `{b.value = "0 "}{c.value = "6"}{d.value = "180"}` etc.?

Comment: OMG it works. Thank you so much I have tried everything. Now only it works

Comment: I'm new here is there a way for me to contribute to your reputation not sure how it works .

Comment: I'll make my comment an actual answer. You then can accept it (click the tick at the upper left of that answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the next block (enveloped in `{...}`) after the `if` condition is executed conditionally, following blocks are executed always. Thus,

```
if(y == 'vv03'||y == 'vv3' ){b.value = "0 "}{c.value = "12"}{d.value = "300"}
```

means that `b.value = "0 "` is executed only if `y == 'vv03'||y == 'vv3'` but `c.value = "12"` and `d.value = "300"` are executed unconditionally.

If you want all those three assignments to be executed only conditionally, put them all into a single block, i.e.

```
if(y == 'vv03'||y == 'vv3' ){b.value = "0 "; c.value = "12"; d.value = "300"}
```

And the same is true for the other two `if`s, too.